# Cannot call showSaveDialog in JavaFX on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx

I'm trying to call `showSaveDialog` in the following way:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle(title);

return fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
```

But the whole program is aborted with the following output:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7d783e3500, pid=22008, tid=140176664483584
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x6a500]  gdk_window_set_geometry_hints+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try     "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/sk_/projects/mjolnirr/hs_err_pid22008.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

How can I get it working?

Comment: Which version of JFX are you using?

Comment: @omgBob I'm using 2.2.51

Comment: There was an issue about a quite similar bug (opening a dialog window) on the javafx jira bugtracker. Due to the bugtracker this issue was fixed in version 2.2.40. So this shouldn't be your problem. In my opinion SIGSEV looks like the error is in JavaFX and not in your code.

Comment: Yep, I've decided to use native Swing dialog in this case, but it is a bad practise

Comment: Indeed but unfortunately it seems that the JavaFX guys have a lot of trouble with the linux port :(

Comment: Yep, there are a lot of troubles with running JavaFX applet on linux host. I'm thinking of moving my project to some other UI library

Answer (score 0):

Had this when using vlcj and fixed it by adding JVM option `-DVLCJ_INITX=no`

Found solution [here](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx/issues/10#issuecomment-165591935)