# Fatal Error when calling showSaveDialog() and showOpenMultipleDialog()

Tags: javafx, java-8, java

The JVM is crashing when I run these two lines:

```
javafx.stage.FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
File targetFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog( mainStage );
```

I am on Ubuntu 16.10, OpenJDK 8 64bit:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.10.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Kernel version:

```
Linux Joshua-PC 4.8.0-59-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 19:38:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried the solution outlined here with no success: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34612376/61248

Here is the top of the error log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8573f34e40, pid=19801, tid=0x00007f850d733700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.10.2-b11)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libpthread.so.0+0x9e40]  pthread_mutex_lock+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f856c325800):  JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=19824, stack(0x00007f850d633000,0x00007f850d734000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00000000006e6f84

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f8573f34e40, RBX=0x00007f856c2e1730, RCX=0x000000000000014c, RDX=0x00007f850d72b8b0
RSP=0x00007f850d72b828, RBP=0x00007f850d72b890, RSI=0x00007f850d72b8a0, RDI=0x00000000006e6f74
R8 =0x00007f850d72b890, R9 =0x00007f856c2919fd, R10=0x00007f854dd43387, R11=0x0000000000000065
R12=0x00007f850d72b88c, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007f85007b27c8, R15=0x00007f850d72ce20
RIP=0x00007f8573f34e40, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f850d72b828)
0x00007f850d72b828:   00007f854dcd8bda 00007f850d72b8a0
0x00007f850d72b838:   00007f850d72b8b0 00007f851358d510
0x00007f850d72b848:   00007f856c29c720 00007f8518f02cc1
0x00007f850d72b858:   7b2d1296d82fd300 00007f856c29c720
0x00007f850d72b868:   00007f8518f02cc1 00007f8518f04494
0x00007f850d72b878:   00007f854dcb4f56 0000000000000003
0x00007f850d72b888:   00007f850d72b930 00007f8500883400
0x00007f850d72b898:   0000000000004d70 0000014e0000014c
0x00007f850d72b8a8:   00007f8500000000 0000015700000156
0x00007f850d72b8b8:   00007f8500000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f850d72b8c8:   7b2d1296d82fd300 00007f8500882a50
0x00007f850d72b8d8:   00007f8500882a84 00007f856c29c720
0x00007f850d72b8e8:   00007f8518ebd79f 0000000000000000
0x00007f850d72b8f8:   00007f854c3e2078 00007f8500883400
0x00007f850d72b908:   7b2d1296d82fd300 00007f850d72b9ec
0x00007f850d72b918:   00007f8500883fa8 00007f850d72b980
0x00007f850d72b928:   00007f8500883fa8 0000000000000000
0x00007f850d72b938:   00007f85007b27c8 00007f850d72ce20
0x00007f850d72b948:   00007f8518ebfcc0 00007f8500883e80
0x00007f850d72b958:   00007f8518e91487 00007f85007b27c8
0x00007f850d72b968:   00007f850087d250 00007f850d72b9a0
0x00007f850d72b978:   00007f8518e4fd1f 00007f850d72ba00
0x00007f850d72b988:   00007f850d72b9f0 00007f850d72b9e0
0x00007f850d72b998:   00007f84c40127b0 00007f84c4012870
0x00007f850d72b9a8:   00007f854c3e3557 0000000000000000
0x00007f850d72b9b8:   0000000000000000 0000000100000001
0x00007f850d72b9c8:   0000000c0000000c 0000000000000000
0x00007f850d72b9d8:   7b2d1296d82fd300 00007f85007b2600
0x00007f850d72b9e8:   00007f850087d250 0000000000000006
0x00007f850d72b9f8:   00007f8518e52e93 0000000000000000
0x00007f850d72ba08:   000001cc0000000c 0000000000000001
0x00007f850d72ba18:   00000006d82fd300 000000004000000c 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f8573f34e40)
0x00007f8573f34e20:   89 0c 25 e0 02 00 00 64 48 c7 04 25 f0 02 00 00
0x00007f8573f34e30:   00 00 00 00 b8 82 00 00 00 e9 e0 f9 ff ff 66 90
0x00007f8573f34e40:   8b 57 10 89 d1 81 e1 7f 01 00 00 90 89 d0 83 e0
0x00007f8573f34e50:   7c 0f 85 99 00 00 00 48 83 ec 08 85 c9 49 89 f8 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007f8573f34e40: pthread_mutex_lock+0 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 at 0x00007f8573f2b000
RBX=0x00007f856c2e1730 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000000000014c is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007f850d72b8b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f856c325800
RSP=0x00007f850d72b828 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f856c325800
RBP=0x00007f850d72b890 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f856c325800
RSI=0x00007f850d72b8a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f856c325800
RDI=0x00000000006e6f74 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f850d72b890 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f856c325800
R9 =0x00007f856c2919fd is an unknown value
R10=0x00007f854dd43387: <offset 0xb0387> in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 at 0x00007f854dc93000
R11=0x0000000000000065 is an unknown value
R12=0x00007f850d72b88c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f856c325800
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007f85007b27c8 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f850d72ce20 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f856c325800


Stack: [0x00007f850d633000,0x00007f850d734000],  sp=0x00007f850d72b828,  free space=994k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x9e40]  pthread_mutex_lock+0x0
C  0x0000000000004d70
```

Full error log here: http://hypnosplayer.org/misc/save-as-error.log

Comment: What kernel version are you using? See comments on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995070/jvm-crashes-on-ubuntu-trying-to-open-javafx-save-dialog-or-open-dialog

Comment: Edited into answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was being caused by the use of an external library [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) for global hotkeys, particularly this line:

```
GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
```

and this line:

```
GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener( globalHotkeyListener );
```

I don't understand why this caused the problem, but removing both of these calls solves the issue. <s>I suppose I'll have to look for a different global hotkey library.</s>

I spoke with the library developer. He reviewed the crash and said it doesn't happen in the library direct, and he indicated that the problem may be with "xcb" and linux. He recommended using an earlier version of the library (v2.0.2 rather than v2.1.0) and that resolved the issue.

Comment: Uh-oh. In this case, it's probably a bug in that JNI library. Could you try to run the JVM with the `-Xcheck:jni` option? Maybe this catches the misuse.

Answer (score 1):

Is this reproducible?

The instruction stream looks like this:

```
   0:   89 0c 25 e0 02 00 00    mov    %ecx,0x2e0
   7:   64 48 c7 04 25 f0 02    movq   $0x0,%fs:0x2f0
   e:   00 00 00 00 00 00 
  14:   b8 82 00 00 00          mov    $0x82,%eax
  19:   e9 e0 f9 ff ff          jmpq   0xfffffffffffff9fe
  1e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

This is from the end of the `__pthread_mutex_lock_full` function in libpthread.  The first instruction faults because it attempts to write to the absolute address `0x2e0`, which is not mapped.  This instruction is the tail of a proper instruction, which writes to the TCB via the `%fs` register override:

```
    993a:       64 48 89 04 25 e0 02    mov    %rax,%fs:0x2e0
    9941:       00 00
```

It's not a simple stray function pointer call, either, because the JVM reports that the faulting instruction is at `pthread_mutex_lock+0`, i.e., the proper start of the function.  So it looks like that the JVM/dynamic linker's view of libpthread are slightly off (shifted by 32 bytes, actually).

**EDIT** As this is perfectly reproducible, it is not a file rewrite of `libpthread.so.0`, as I originally suspected.  It is likely some sort of memory corruption which flips a bit in a function pointer.  If `-Xcheck:jni` does not provide any hints, this needs an extending debugging session with GDB to identify the root cause (running the JVM under `valgrind` probably has too many false positives).

Comment: See my answer, which seems to suggest the problem is linked to a global hotkey library I am using. Do you think that library could be causing the issue you see? (Sorry, but I don't understand your post well enough to determine that myself.)

Comment: I assume that this happens every time? Then my theory about the file rewrite is wrong.

Comment: Yea, happens every time. It also happens when I call showOpenMultipleDialog(). I checked against an earlier version and saw that it was working in that version, and did a git bisect until I found the commit that caused the problem, which was that library I mentioned. If those calls are included, the crash happens every single time. Without those calls included, the crash never happens.

Comment: Okay, then my answer isn't all that helpful, sorry.